# WPF - Exposing child control as a dependency property

Tags: wpf

I want to make child properties available for binding in a control that I am building. Let me explain this:

I have a control hierarchy:

BaseControl

AControl : BaseControl

BControl : BaseControl

All controls are simple WPF controls with their specific behaviors (and thus their dependency properties). Now I want to create another control:
CControl : BaseControl

But that control has actually two same controls of type AControl. So, pseudo WPF code would be:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <AControl
      Grid.Column="0">
  <AControl
      Grid.Column="1">
</Grid>
```

Now, I would like to expose control properties of both instances to the CControl, so that anyone could now use properties for binding outside the control.

For instance, it would be nice to have something like this:

```
<CControl A1Control.Text="Test1" A1.Control.Text="Test2"/>
```

I know that it is not possible (at least I am not aware of it) but what would be the best approach to expose child properties. I have dozens child dependency properties, so I would need to create "copy" for each instance (for instance: Text1Property, Text2Property, Margin1Property, Margin2Property etc.).

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can bind a list for a Texts property and use the first element of the list for the first child control.

Comment: How about exposing a `Control1Style` and `Control2Style` and then everyone can change text, margin etc via style setters?

Comment: @ganchito55 Well, that doesn't seems right to me, note, there are dozens different properties, so basically I would need to create list for every one of them.

Comment: @grek40 It seems like a good idea, if I am following you here, this is similar to what calendar control has for its parts (day, month...). I'll try this and see how it is working, My biggest concern here is - that I will need to overwrite style in the internal control, so this is a limiting factor, but I can tweak that from C#.